# How to declare a pointer to a function of return type X and input parameter A?

Tags: c++, pointers

What is the general form of declaring a pointer to a function which, say is of return type X and accepts the input parameter &Y?

is it:

```
X my_function(Y &y){
    //code
}

X (*my_pointer) (Y &y) = my_function;
```

?

Comment: Sometimes "legal" code doesn't do what we intend though? :)

Comment: cdecl.org would tell you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
X (*fptr)(Y&) = my_function;
```

Or:

```
auto fptr = my_function; // c++11
```

Or:

```
std::function<X(Y&)> fptr(my_function); // c++11, boost::function if not
```

Answer (score 2):

What you wrote is OK, but you normally do not write the name of function arguments if you just want to declare a function pointer of that type:

```
X (*my_pointer) (Y&) = my_function;
```

Depending on your taste, you may want to be more C++11-ish and write:

```
#include <type_traits>

std::add_pointer<X(Y&)>::type my_pointer = my_function;
```

It can get even more readable with a template alias:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
using AddPointer = typename std::add_pointer<T>::type;

AddPointer<X(Y&)> my_pointer = my_function;
```

Or even use `auto` and forget about naming the function type explicitly, [as suggested by hmjd in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16627757/1932150). If you would later need to retrieve the type, you could do:

```
decltype(my_pointer)
```

Answer (score 0):

- is it:

  ```
  X my_function(Y &y){
     //code
  }

  X (*my_pointer) (Y &y) = my_function;
  ```

  ?

Yes

Comment: @MM. I didn't find better way to quote question containing code

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @alecxe My answer is "Yes". All the rest is quote of OP's question